# ContentPresenter TextElement Property Inheritance

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a common DataTemplate, **NameTemplate**, that I use inside other DataTemplates. I have deliberately left the **FontSize** and **FontFamily** properties undefined so that the consuming DataTemplate can set TextElement attached properties and have **NameTemplate**'s TextBlock inherit those properties.

The problem is the TextBlock inside **NameTemplate** does not inherit those TextElement attached properties. See code below and my working solution to the problem.

I am posting to ask if there's a better way of solving this and perhaps an explanation as to why my solution works? Also, at the end of this post is a question regarding another problem I'm having with this solution.

Here is the **NameTemplate**;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" DataType="{x:Type common:Contact}">
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding MiddleInitial, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='', FallbackValue='', StringFormat='{}{0}. '}"/><Run Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here is an example of a consuming DataTemplate;

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type common:Contact}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource SubHeadingTextElementStyle}"/>
        <!-- Other Template Stuff -->
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The Style **SubHeadingTextElementStyle** looks like this;

```
<Style x:Key="SubHeadingTextElementStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTextElementStyle}">
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="{telerik:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=FontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="{telerik:Windows8Resource ResourceKey=FontSizeL}"/>
</Style>
```

To make this work as intended I have to add the following bindings to the **NameTemplate** TextBlock;

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" DataType="{x:Type common:Contact}">
    <TextBlock FontSize="{Binding (TextElement.FontSize), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" FontFamily="{Binding (TextElement.FontFamily), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
               Foreground="{Binding (TextElement.Foreground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" FontWeight="{Binding (TextElement.FontWeight), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <Run Text="{Binding Title, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding MiddleInitial, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue='', FallbackValue='', StringFormat='{}{0}. '}"/><Run Text="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Note the RelativeSource Self bindings to TextElement attached property.

Another issue I've encountered with this approach, in one of my consuming templates I set the TextElement.FontWeight property to a binding with a BooleanToFontWeightConverter - this binding does not work though - the Convert method of the value converter is never called. I assume this is due to the solution I've implemented as the converter works as intended in other scenarios.